# Get publishing point programmatically from Website

Tags: iis-7, publishing

I use Application Host COM Protoco to get publishing point under one website, when the physical path is on the SERVER, such as (c:\path). it works well, publishing points are retrieved by COM and control the operational state (Start, Stop and Shutdown) kindly.

But when the website's physical path changed to another computer (\10.10.10.10\path), it doesn't work, publishing point can not be retrieved in this path.

Additional :  all job under IIS 7

Please help me, If anyone knew it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

DCOMCFG error, we need sepcifed user for runing the application.

Steps:

1. Run dcomcnfg.exe
2. open DCOM ahadmin properties settings.
3. select identity tab and choose the third radio option.

But, I got another problem. the publishing point state can not be controled programmaticlly.